# Firefox extension: Positioning panels

Tags: firefox, xul, positioning

I'm making a Firefox extension and I want to position a XUL panel element exactly above a search box when a person types text in the search box-- almost like autocomplete.  How do I do that?

Thanks!

Edit: I've been looking at using auto complete and using my own nxIAutoComplete implementation but I'm a bit too new to extension development to do that and know what I am doing.  Can anyone provide any help?  I feel the solution is simple, but I just can't figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Positioning

Comment: Indeed, the before_start position appears to be the way to go.